# How does the issue of premeditation factor in when the death penalty is considered for felony murder?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, interpretation

How does the fact that [felony murder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felony_murder_and_the_death_penalty_in_the_United_States) is at least in principle murder without premeditation, factor in when the issue of the death penalty is being considered as punishment for the crime? Surely the death penalty should only be used on the most heinous of murder cases and not on those who are in some ways an accidental death.

Comment: The title asks a question, then the body makes a rhetorical point about ethical issues that are only relevant if the title's answer is positive, but off-topic here regardless. Please clarify whether you actually want information or just to post a rant.

Comment: This is not a rant, what part of this comes off like a rant? I will improve this post like you suggest but I don't know what part of asking how premeditation factors into the death penalty are ranting

Comment: My suggestion to improve the question is: (1) delete the irrelevant political opinion in the 2nd sentence. What you think *should be the case* (regardless of merit) isn't relevant to the law (2) Clarify what exactly you are asking. Are you asking whether the fact that it is a felony murder rather than an intended murder is a factor that the court considers when deciding to impose the death penalty? That could be a valid legal question. Or are you asking whether it is morally justified that the death penalty should apply to felony murder? That would be off-topic since it isn't about law.

Comment: @NeilMeyer your second sentence definitely comes across as a rant / political opinion

Comment: I'm allowed to voice my opinion in a question, there is nothing I have ever read on this site that said anyone cannot express their opinions in a question. This is an entirely reasonable question now with the edit. It is not a political view, it is a view on a law

Comment: The [tag:united-states] tag implies that you are asking about federal law, which does have a felony murder statute carrying the death penalty, so one could answer in that context.  But only very few murder prosecutions are done under federal law. If you wanted to know about a particular state instead, please clarify.  ("All US states" would be too broad.)

Comment: I think the answer boils down to: in [federal law](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1111), premeditation is not a required element of felony murder.  It is one of many possible [aggravating factors](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/3592) that are considered when a court decides whether to impose a death sentence, but again is not by itself a required factor.  So Congress evidently *does* consider felony murder among the "most heinous of murder cases" and disagrees with you that it is akin to an "accident".  I don't know what more is to be said.

Comment: Is that the sort of answer you want?  If you want people to debate whether this law is right or wrong, then that *is* off topic.  Indeed, the problem with giving your opinion on a law in a question is that it encourages answerers with different opinions to respond, and the question turns into a debate and usually gets shut down.  Or if answers are not allowed to respond with their own opinions, then it seems unfair that only your side is seen.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge The US tag definition says "For questions specific to the United States as a whole, or that span multiple state jurisdictions. " In practice it is often used when the specific state of the US is not given. So use of that tag does **not** imply that the question is about US federal law.

Comment: Opinions on what the law *should* be, are necessarily political. A question that started exactly the same way as this one, and ended saying *"Surely the death penalty should be used on all criminals, and not only on those who happened to kill someone along the way?"* does not change the legal question in any way, making the second sentence both unnecessary to the question itself and inappropriate as an op-ed piece, which is not what Stack Exchange posts are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While felony murder was an offense originally invented to single out more culpable murders from less culpable murders, with only the former punishable by death, as opposed to imposing the death penalty on everyone convicted of murder, it has evolved into a means of convicting someone of first degree murder who otherwise would not have been guilty of the crime of murder (or even conspiracy to commit murder) at all.

In a [typical felony murder statute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felony_murder_and_the_death_penalty_in_the_United_States), everyone who participates in a felony designated in the felony murder statute that results in a death at the hands of any participate, without regard to premeditation or involvement in the murder itself, is guilty of felony murder, rather than merely the underlying felony crime.

Typically, felony murder is one way to be guilty of first degree murder and typically the punishment for first degree murder is either life in prison without possibility of parole, or the death penalty (if the state has  death penalty), as determined in a second phase of the jury trial after the guilt phase is completed.

At the death penalty phase, following evidentiary presentation by the prosecution and the defense of aggravating and mitigating factors, in addition to the evidence presented in the guilty or innocence phase of the trial (at which the same death qualified jury convicted the defendant), [the jury (except in Nebraska where a panel of three judges makes this decision, and in Montana where a sole judge makes this decision)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_in_the_United_States#Sentencing) must determine if the aggravating factors in the case outweigh the mitigating factors, if any.

The fact that the defendant (now a convicted murderer) was a knowing participant in a felony is typically an aggravating factor. The possibility, if established, that the defendant (now a convicted murderer) was not expecting that violence would occur and did not participate in the killing would be a mitigating factor.

> The Supreme Court of the United States has held that the Eighth
> Amendment to the United States Constitution does not prohibit imposing
> the death penalty for felony murder. The Supreme Court has created a
> two-part test to determine when the death penalty is an appropriate
> punishment for felony murder. Under *Enmund v. Florida*, 458 U.S. 782 (1982), the death
> penalty may not be imposed on someone who did not kill, attempt to
> kill, or intend that a killing take place. However, under *Tison v.
> Arizona*, 481 U.S. 137 (1987), the death penalty may be imposed on someone who was a major
> participant in the underlying felony and acted with reckless
> indifference to human life.

So, the constitutional standard for imposing the death penalty for felony murder is higher than the constitutional standard for imposing the default life without possibility of parole (LWOP) sentence for felony murder.

Keep in mind also that following a jury imposition of the death penalty that this decision will be upheld if any reasonable jury could have found facts sufficient to impose the death penalty by finding some evidence to be credible and other evidence to be less credible, whether or not that was the most plausible interpretation of the facts and whether or not this was actually the reason for the jury's decision.

Also keep in mind that the death qualification of the jury (i.e. striking for cause from the jury pool anyone who is categorically opposed to imposing the death penalty), means that juries in cases where the death penalty is an option are systemically biased in favor of the prosecution in the process of how the judge guilty or innocence, and also, in their evaluation of aggravating and mitigating factors in a case.